# innerHTML trims some of the string in internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, innerhtml

in the below code , the property innerHTML trims last two characters . It works fine in mozilla.

```
var x=document.createElement("TD");
x.innerHTML='abcd&00&dg';
alert(x.innerHTML);

</script>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: If you're setting text, consider appending a _#text_ node

Comment: Do you want to type space in the string or what?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `&amp;`, `&#x00026;` or `&#38;` in place of `&`.

See http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: that helped. But i was hoping for a reasoning as to why does it trim the last two characters?